# How to group data when using BatchBlocks?

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

Consider the following type that gets produced by an external system as a continous dataflow;

```
public class Point 
{
    public decimal Bid;
    public decimal Ask; 
    public string Currency; 
}
```

Upon receiving a **specific** amount of items I have to do some calculations based on that data. So to do my calculations I need for example 10 points where `Currency` contains the same value and acts as key. So a group would look like this:

```
var point0 = new Point { Currency = "EUR", Bid = 12.5M, Ask = 10.5M }
var point1 = new Point { Currency = "EUR", Bid = 11.7M, Ask = 10.8M }
[...]
var point9 = new Point { Currency = "EUR", Bid = 13.5M, Ask = 11.5M }
```

So I thought a `BatchBlock` would be the perfect choice for this type of requirement.

```
var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<Point>(10); 
// batchBlock.Post(...)
```

However this wouldn't allow me to *group* together points of the same currency-group. The points won't come in in order. So I think I need a `BatchBlock` for each currency-group.

But how would I feed this BatchBlocks based on the currency? Do I need to create a custom dataflow block?

---

**[Edit]**

I had to come up with a custom dataflow block and solved it by using `DataflowBlock.Encapsulate()`. This solution seems to work and batch/group the incoming instances of `Point`.

However I am not sure if this is the *intented* way to do this... also I will have to think about error handling...

```
private static IPropagatorBlock<Point, Point[]> CreateSorterBlock(int batchSize)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, List<Point>>();
    var outgoing = new BufferBlock<Point[]>();
    var sorter = new Action<Point>(point =>
    {
        // This currencyPair has never been seen
        if (!data.ContainsKey(point.CurrencyPair))
        {
            data.Add(point.CurrencyPair, new List<Point>());
            data[point.CurrencyPair].Add(point);
        }
        // Other points have already been collected, so add 
        // to the list of points 
        else
        {
            data[point.CurrencyPair].Add(point);
        }

        // batch is full so lets send it out
        if (data[point.CurrencyPair].Count == batchSize)
        {
            outgoing.Post(data[point.CurrencyPair].ToArray());
            data.Remove(point.CurrencyPair);
        }
    });

    var incoming = new ActionBlock<Point>(sorter);

    return DataflowBlock.Encapsulate(incoming, outgoing);
}
```

Tests:

```
[Fact]
public void Should_Batch_And_Group_Messages()
{
    var rand = new Random();

    var feederBlock = new BufferBlock<Point>();
    var sorterBlock = CreateSorterBlock(3);
    var resultBlock = new ActionBlock<Point[]>(points =>
    {
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            this.output.WriteLine($"Currency: {point.CurrencyPair}"
                + $" Ask: {point.Ask} Bid: {point.Bid}");
        }
        this.output.WriteLine($"End of resultBlock");
    });

    feederBlock.LinkTo(sorterBlock);
    sorterBlock.LinkTo(resultBlock);

    feederBlock.Post(new Point{
        Ask = rand.Next(), Bid = rand.Next(), CurrencyPair = "EUR/USD" });
    feederBlock.Post(new Point{
        Ask = rand.Next(), Bid = rand.Next(), CurrencyPair = "XAU/USD" });
    feederBlock.Post(new Point{
        Ask = rand.Next(), Bid = rand.Next(), CurrencyPair = "EUR/USD" });
    feederBlock.Post(new Point{
        Ask = rand.Next(), Bid = rand.Next(), CurrencyPair = "XAU/USD" });
    feederBlock.Post(new Point{
        Ask = rand.Next(), Bid = rand.Next(), CurrencyPair = "EUR/USD" });
    feederBlock.Post(new Point{
        Ask = rand.Next(), Bid = rand.Next(), CurrencyPair = "XAU/USD" });
    feederBlock.Post(new Point{
        Ask = rand.Next(), Bid = rand.Next(), CurrencyPair = "XPT/USD" });
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using the `DataflowBlock.Encapsulate` method is great, but to make it complete you must handle the `Completion` of the incoming block. Otherwise the generated block will never be completed, and the remaining points will not be consumed.

I improved your code a bit by using [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync) instead of `Post`, so that the generated block will continue working correctly in case you later decide to limit the capacity of the block, by configuring the [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) option.

The [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) option should not be configured, because the code running inside the incoming block in not thread-safe. Parallelism should not be needed anyway because the workload of the block is very small, and adding thread-safety will probably make it slower than faster.

```
public static IPropagatorBlock<Point, Point[]> CreateBatchByCurrencyBlock(
    int batchSize)
{
    var grouped = new Dictionary<string, List<Point>>(
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    var outgoing = new BufferBlock<Point[]>();
    var incoming = new ActionBlock<Point>(async point =>
    {
        List<Point> list;
        if (!grouped.TryGetValue(point.Currency, out list))
        {
            list = new List<Point>();
            grouped.Add(point.Currency, list);
        }
        list.Add(point);
        if (list.Count >= batchSize)
        {
            await outgoing.SendAsync(list.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            list.Clear();
        }
    });

    incoming.Completion.ContinueWith(async t =>
    {
        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            foreach (var list in grouped.Values)
            {
                if (list.Count >= 0)
                {
                    await outgoing.SendAsync(list.ToArray())
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
                    list.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            ((ITargetBlock<Point[]>)outgoing).Fault(t.Exception.InnerException);
        }
        outgoing.Complete();
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
    TaskScheduler.Default);

    return DataflowBlock.Encapsulate(incoming, outgoing);
}
```